# Powershell hangs on Get-PnPListItem foreach

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to get a list of largest files or files with too many versions, so I am using
$list = Get-PnPListItem ,
but it hangs on foreach($item in $list) as the folder has about 300000 items.
So is there any way to overcome this issue (do it in chunks etc)?
Thanks

In response to Jerry_MSFT - I dont get an option to add app password for my user account
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SharePoint Online CSOM PowerShell instead like this:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#Config Parameters
$SiteURL="https://Crescent.SharePoint.com"
$ListName="Projects"
$BatchSize= 2000
 
Try {
    $Cred= Get-Credential
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
         
    #Get the List
    $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
    $Ctx.Load($List)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    #Define Query to get List Items in batch
    $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $Query.ViewXml = @"
    <View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
        <Query>
            <OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">$BatchSize</RowLimit>
    </View>
"@
 
    #Get List Items in Batch
    Do
    {
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
        $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $ListItems.count
        $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    }
    While($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
 
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Getting List Items:" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

$Query.ListItemCollectionPosition is used to paging the ListItemCollection returned so that it will avoid the ListView Threshold issue.

Comment: We are using MFA, I could not get it to work with MFA

Comment: Nerver mind, you can use AppPassword instead of real user password in the PowerShell to work with MFA::  https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/connect-sharepoint-online-powershell-using-mfa.html

Comment: Thanks, will give it a test

Comment: Well, the problem is that we have hundreds of sites and I dont have permissions for all of them. I could give myself permissions, but again - its hundreds of sites. So I created tenant wide sharepoint app with read permissions to all sites, but i cannot find how yo authenticate to SharePoint with SP registered app when using ClientContext.

Comment: CSOM didn't provide app-only authentication function, you could use OfficeDevPnP.Core instead:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-to-sharepoint-online-site-with-app-only-authentication/